# Yet struggling to parse JSON with jq

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv, jq

I'm slowly getting a grip of how jq works but am still far from mastering it.
Now I'm in a situation I've kinda managed to get what I wanted but not to display it the way I want. I'm sure it's quite simple but I'm missing it...

Here's a sample of the JSON I want to parse:

```
{
    "sites": [
        {
            "site_id": 123456,
            "status": "configured",
            "domain": "www.domain.com",
            "account_id": 654321,
            "security": {
                "waf": {
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "action": "block_request",
                            "action_text": "Block",
                            "id": "sqli",
                            "name": "SQLi"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "block_request",
                            "action_text": "Block",
                            "id": "xss",
                            "name": "XSS"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "alert",
                            "action_text": "Alert",
                            "id": "path_vector",
                            "name": "Path Vector"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "res": 0,
    "res_message": "OK",
    "debug_info": {
        "id-info": "9123"
    }
}
```

I only need a few details and put them in CSV format, here's what I did so far:

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.sites [] | [.site_id,.domain],(.security.waf.rules[] | [.action_text]) | @csv'
```

This is the ouput I got:

```
123456,"www.domain.com"
"Block"
"Block"
"Alert"
```

Not so bad, but what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
123456,"www.domain.com","Block","Block","Alert"
```

Same result, just displayed in one single line.
I went over the man pages and fiddled around for a while to no avail.
Is it possible to do it or I need a different tool to manipulate it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First lets discuss why you received that result.

When you use `[]` to extract items from objects/arrays, it yields a value for every item in that object/array.

```
.sites[]
```

produces a result for the every value in your `sites` array (which in this case there's only one).

Another thing to note, using a comma (`,`) will yield the delimited values within that expression.

```
[.site_id,.domain]
```

The comma here produces two values, the `site_id` and the `domain`.  But, those values are collected in to an array (as denoted by the square brackets).

Putting this into the next part of the expression

```
.security.waf.rules[] | [.action_text]
```

The first part goes through all the rules objects in that array. Then for each of those objects, creates an array containing the `action_text`.  This creates three arrays (one for each of the rules).

Put this together with the previous part of the expression (slightly reformatted)

```
([.site_id,.domain]) , (.security.waf.rules[] | [.action_text])
```

This all together produces four arrays, the array containing the `site_id` and `domain`, followed by the three arrays of `action_text`.

Then for each of those four arrays, a csv row is created giving you the results you see.

---

So how can we get the desired results?

First, we'll want to start go through all the sites.  I'm assuming you want a row per site.

```
.sites[]
```

Then for each site, we need to build an array of the values in that row.  Start with what we have direct access to.

```
.site_id, .domain
```

Then produce the `action_text` values.

```
.security.waf.rules[].action_text
```

Note we're not putting the `action_text` in a separate array, we just want the value.

Now we put those values together.

```
.site_id, .domain, (.security.waf.rules[].action_text)
```

This creates five values as we discussed, but we want to collect them in an array so we may pass it to the `@csv` filter.

```
[.site_id, .domain, (.security.waf.rules[].action_text)]
```

Putting everything together will give us this filter:

```
.sites[] | [.site_id, .domain, (.security.waf.rules[].action_text)] | @csv
```

Of course there's many approaches you can take to get these values (like building out arrays separately then combining them) but this is the most direct.

Comment: Awesome @Jeff Mercado !!! Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation too!

Answer (score 3):

All the values to be printed in a CSV row must be collected in a JSON array.  A solution that is very similar to your attempt would therefore be:

```
.sites[]
| [.site_id, .domain, (.security.waf.rules[] | .action_text) ]
| @csv
```

By the way, there is no need to use `cat`:

```
jq -r -f program.jq test.json
```